# Использовать и rtl и ltr стили bootstrap sass в проекте?

Tags: bootstrap, scss

Использую bootstrap5 scss.

Подключаю у себя стили для ltr стандартно:
`@import "~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";`

**Вопрос:** как подключить или включить rtl bootstrap 5 scss стили ?

Из инструкции ничего не понятно, кроме как стандартно через link подключать, а нужно именно в scss.

Comment: Попробуйте посмотреть здесь: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67055428/how-to-enable-bootstrap-rtl-in-scss